# setting and retrieving spinner value just like asp's dropdownlist - mono for android

Tags: c#, spinner, xamarin.android

i really don't get how I can use a spinner just like asp.net's dropdownlist, where you have one value that is displayed for the user, and a hidden custom value that I can use with the change event.

like in asp.net, you can just do this:

```
string value = "somevalue";
dropdownlistID.Items.Add(new ListItem("text",value));
```

and in the event I can just retrieve it with `dropdownlistID.SelectedValue`

If anyone have a link that can explain this to me, or any other suggestions, please help!
I'm making an android app in vs2010 with mono for android.

Regards, Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create an ArrayAdapter, the same way you would to fill a ListView.

```
 spinTime = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinTimeChoose);
 List<string> spinnerItems = new List<string>();
 ArrayAdapter adapter  new ArrayAdapter<string> (this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem,spinnerItems);

 adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
 spinTime.Adapter = adapter;
 spinTime.ItemSelected += (s, e) =>
 { 
  Log.Debug("SpinnerItems", spinnerItems[e.Position]);           
 }
```

hope it helps

edit: i think i now get your question :)
below is an example for an custom Adapter for a list of clearances. sorry for the hardcoded german strings. The important part is the getView method. It gets called everytime a new listitem gets into the view of the user. you have to inflate a new view, or if not null reuse the convertView and fill it with the values from your list.

```
class ClearanceListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private readonly List<Clearance> _clearances;
    private readonly Activity _context;

    public ClearanceListAdapter(List<Clearance> Clearances, Activity context)
    {
        _clearances = Clearances;
        _context = context;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return _clearances.Count(); }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public Clearance GetClearance (int position)
    {
        return _clearances.ElementAt(position);

    }

    public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View view = (convertView ?? _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ClearanceListItem, parent, false));

        Clearance clearance = _clearances[position];


        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtClearanceDescription).Text = clearance.Description;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtStartDate).Text = clearance.Start.ToString("g");
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtEndDate).Text = clearance.End.ToString("g");

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: to some extent it does, the only thing i don't understand is where I set the equivalent to the dropdownlist itemvalue. I know how to get a spinner with some items in it, it's the part where I assign a custom value to a specific item that just won't sink in.  sorry for being noobish ^^ i would be very pleased if you, or anyone else could explain the code ;) thank you for the fast response also.

Comment: their is no equivalent. you point a list to the adapter and the spinner fires the ItemSelected event, giving you the index (based on the given list) that was selected then you would have to get the selected object from the list.